# Make Guake Float in i3wm

Tags: configuration, window-manager, i3, tiling-wm, guake

I want to default Guake to open as a floating window under i3. I created an entry under ~/.i3/config that reads as the following.

My code is -

```
for_window [class="guake"] floating enable
```

My xprop for the window is -

```
$ xprop
GDK_TIMESTAMP_PROP(GDK_TIMESTAMP_PROP) = 0x61
WM_STATE(WM_STATE):
                window state: Normal
                icon window: 0x0
_NET_WM_DESKTOP(CARDINAL) = 4294967295
_NET_WM_STATE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_STATE_ABOVE, _NET_WM_STATE_STICKY, _NET_WM_STATE_SKIP_TASKBAR, _NET_WM_STATE_SKIP_PAGER
WM_HINTS(WM_HINTS):
                Client accepts input or input focus: True
                Initial state is Normal State.
                window id # of group leader: 0x1200001
XdndAware(ATOM) = BITMAP
_MOTIF_DRAG_RECEIVER_INFO(_MOTIF_DRAG_RECEIVER_INFO) = 0x6c, 0x0, 0x5, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x10, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0
_MOTIF_WM_HINTS(_MOTIF_WM_HINTS) = 0x2, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0
_NET_WM_SYNC_REQUEST_COUNTER(CARDINAL) = 18874401
_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL
_NET_WM_USER_TIME(CARDINAL) = 3768611
_NET_WM_USER_TIME_WINDOW(WINDOW): window id # 0x1200020
WM_CLIENT_LEADER(WINDOW): window id # 0x1200001
_NET_WM_PID(CARDINAL) = 1265
WM_LOCALE_NAME(STRING) = "en_US.UTF-8"
WM_CLIENT_MACHINE(STRING) = "class-VirtualBox"
WM_NORMAL_HINTS(WM_SIZE_HINTS):
                program specified location: 0, 0
                program specified minimum size: 1 by 1
                window gravity: North
WM_PROTOCOLS(ATOM): protocols  WM_DELETE_WINDOW, WM_TAKE_FOCUS, _NET_WM_PING, _NET_WM_SYNC_REQUEST
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "guake", "Main.py"
WM_ICON_NAME(STRING) = "Guake Terminal"
_NET_WM_ICON_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "Guake Terminal"
WM_NAME(STRING) = "Guake Terminal"
_NET_WM_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "Guake Terminal"
```

How do I make it so that guake always floats when opened in i3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct command is -

```
for_window [instance="guake"] floating enable
```

Add the above to ~/.i3/config in order to allow guake to function and float as normal.